# How to pass values throught URL using ajax and jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination, parameter-passing

So i have a problem with passing variable through url in ajax-jquery... I have  this:

```
function showBrand(brandId){
    $.ajax({ 
        url:'brandFilter.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: {brandId:brandId},
        dataType:'html',
        success:function(resultHTML){
            $("#filteredProducts").html(resultHTML); 
        }
    }); 
}
```

This works when i'm passing just one brandId ,depends which one link user clicked. I added pagination so i wanna show 3 products per page, so i have to pass both pageNumber and brandId when user clicks on page number... Can you help me please? I guess it should be like

```
index.php?pageNumber=2&brandId=2
```

or i'm wrong?

Comment: just do `data: {brandId:brandId, pageNumber: 1}`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add multiple data or serialize it and pass it through ajax as,

```
function showBrand(brandId){
$.ajax({ 
    url:'brandFilter.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: {brandId:brandId, pageNumber:pageNumber},
    dataType:'html',
    success:function(resultHTML){
        $("#filteredProducts").html(resultHTML); 
    }
});
```

You could also use `data: $("#form").serialize();`, 
where `#form` is id of your form in html.